# Redirect to a page from another page and show the hidden divs there

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page (page.html) which has 4 main sections in it. each section is a page on the website and has many "mini" sections in it.
when you open it (page.html) for the first time, it's blank until you click on a link from the navbar.

I have another page (index.html) which has some questions in it. when you finish, it shows the results and guides you to the pages you should check.

well, I'm having troubles redirecting to page.html AND show required sections.

none of the solutions I found helped me and some weren't clear to me.
in the code below I figured out how to redirect to page.html, but I don't know how to un-hide the sections I need.

```
$('#firstChoice').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ChoiceCareer')) {
        window.location = 'page.html';
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('ChoiceFriendship')) {
        window.location = 'page.html';
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('ChoiceFamily')) {
        window.location = 'page.html';
    }

});
```

So can anyone help me? how do I make sections appear on the index.html from page.html?

Comment: Need to use url search parameters or url hash and parse url in page.html to do the hide/show

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Something like `window.location = 'page.html#career'` ... in other page use `window.location.hash` to get `#career` from url

Comment: In page.html I put window.location.hash and in index.html I put page.html/#career?

Comment: Yes....then use that `hash` value to figure out which element(s) to show/hide. Use different hash value for each of your conditions above

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank u!